# Javascript function "return this" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function, it just runs through a list of objects and return the correct one:

```
function findLine(textElement,caretIndex){
    jQuery.each(textElement.lines(), function() {
        if(this.startIndex <= caretIndex && this.endIndex >= caretIndex) {
            alert(this);
            return this;
        }
   });
}
```

When I call it with this I get `undefined` in return.

```
line = findLine(textElement,caretIndex);
alert(line);
```

Oddly enough when I run `line = findLine(textElement,caretIndex);` the alert within the function is fired and return the correct results. So `this` is the correct value, however when the second alert outside the function is fired I get `undefined`.

Either there's something wrong happening when I'm returning the value from the function or it's something to do with assigning that value to a variable. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're only returning from inter function, not the main function.

Comment: That's not what `each` does.  I think you're thinking of `map` or `grep`.  And you aren't returning anything from `findLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation on [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> > We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

So your `return this` statement is essentially a `continue` statement because `this` is non-false. Altering your function to this might work (untested...and there are probably better functions to use than .each() such as .filter() or .grep()):

```
function findLine(textElement,caretIndex){
    var result;
    jQuery.each(textElement.lines(), function() {
        if(this.startIndex <= caretIndex && this.endIndex >= caretIndex) {
            alert(this);
            result = this;
            return false; // returning false in the callback just causes the loop to exit
        }
   });

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're `return this` is in a callback for the `jQuery.each` method, and your `findLine` doesn't return anything.

```
function findLine(textElement,caretIndex){
    return jQuery.each(textElement.lines(), function() {
        if(this.startIndex <= caretIndex && this.endIndex >= caretIndex) {
            alert(this);
            return this;
        }
   });
}
```

If you `return` the `jQuery.each` call you'll end up with a jQuery object that contains each `this` that you're wanting.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you might really be wanting a [`jQuery.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) call if you're trying to reduce the items in the array